# BCM43142 WIFI became unrecognized suddenly after reboot

Tags: networking, wireless, broadcom

Up until an hour ago I had access to the internet and then my battery drained and my PC closed and when I booted it up again suddenly I had no connection.

I tried a bunch of stuff I found online but nothing.

1. There is no *enable wireless* option
2. In **System Settings > Network** there is only network proxy no wireless
3. The output of `rfkill list all` lists only Bluetooth
4. `sudo lshw -c network` lists an ethernet controller and a network controller
5. It's a dual boot system, and internet works fine on Windows
6. `sudo ifconfig` lists only `lo`

Output of `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` is:

```
 0d:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11B/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev01)
 Subsystem: Hewlett - Packard Company Device [103c:804a]
 Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
```

Comment: Please run: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` Write down the result and post it here as an edit to your question.

Comment: @chili555, I posted the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What solved my problem (for now and hopefully for good!) is [Yufenyuy Veyeh Dider](https://askubuntu.com/users/531149/yufenyuy-veyeh-dider)'s answer, but I am posting my own answer to explain in detail what I did.
Since I had no wireless or ethernet I found the right package on another machine and copied it to my PC via usb.

In my case the package was [this one](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/bcmwl-kernel-source), amd64 architecture because it's a 64 bit machine. Double clicking the package opened the software center but it wouldn't let me install it citing  `This requires installation of untrusted packages.`

I searched online and found that you can install  `deb` files by the following command:

```
 sudo dpkg -i DEB_PACKAGE_NAME
```

which I did but another package `dkms` was requested and failed to fetch since I have no internet connection. The name of it was `dkms_2.2.0.3-2ubuntu6.1_all.deb` so I found it the same way as the `bcmwl-kernel-source` and installed it using `sudo dpkg -i  dkms_2.2.0.3-2ubuntu6.1_all.deb`. After it installed, I installed the original package `bcmwl-kernel-source` and my wireless started working again!

I hope this is the end of it. But I have no idea why this happened out of the blue, when wireless was working perfectly an hour ago.

`rfkill list all` now lists:

```
0:phy0: Wireless LAN
1:brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
2:hci0: Bluetooth
```

`ifconfig -a` lists:

```
lo
wlp13so
```

`sudo lshw -c network` lists an ethernet controller and a wireless interface.

Does that mean that everything is as it should be?
I have no idea why this happened in the first place, I hope my answer helps anyone with the same problem.

Again thanks [Yufenyuy Veyeh Dider](https://askubuntu.com/users/531149/yufenyuy-veyeh-dider)!

Comment: I believe everything is fine now. I assume that you can connect and access the internet as expected. If so, you are all set.

Comment: Yes everything looks fine. Do you have any idea why this happened? Could it be because of the drained battery?

Comment: I have no idea. I'm just glad it's working as expected.

Comment: I realized Ethernet still isn't working. The card is `Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)`. Is the process for reinstating Ethernet the same as Wireless?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a problem of drivers...
I can see `Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge`.
Your Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11B/g/n [14e4:4365] should work with the Broadcom proprietary driver. If you have an ethernet cable please connect and execute the following with the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

When this is done, unplug the cable and verify that your wireless is working .

Comment: No ethernet connection either. I connected with the cable but nothing.

Comment: Can I find the package online in another machine and transfer it via usb? If I can, my PC has Ubuntu 15.10 and wireless card as seen above. Is this: http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/bcmwl-kernel-source the right one?